# How can I install 'Adobe Flash Player' offline?

Tags: installation, flash, offline

My friend has a computer with Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit, but he has **no internet connection**. He'd like to install the **Adobe Flash Player** on his computer. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can download it from the Adobe website. So download it from a computer with an usb drive and use a usb drive to copy it to the offline computer.

http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash

Pick the tar.gz file archive as download option to download the offline installation for ubuntu. The tar.gz archive contains instructions how you can install it for the default browser firefox or how you can run the flash player itself.

Comment: Currently there are two tar.gz files. You should choose the first/upper one.

Answer (score 2):

He needs to install the package `adobe-flashplugin`.

Step 1: Get the download URLs in a file:

Execute the following command on your friend's PC:

```
apt-get -y install --print-uris adobe-flashplugin | cut -d\' -f2 | grep http:// > apturls
```

Step 2: Copy this file (apturls, in his home folder) to a machine with Internet access, and execute the following command to download the packages:

```
wget -i path-to-apturls-file
```

Step 3: Now get those downloaded packages to your machine, and install them using :

```
cd path-to-the-downloaded-packages-directory

sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Done!

Comment: I'm sorry. I left a \ before ('). Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Comment: Did you try running that command with a package that is already installed on your system? Then it won't produce anything in the 'apturls' file. Let me know if you tried with a non-existing package and still the file turned out to be blank.

Comment: The first command is run on the computer that has no internet connection. That means Siraj's friend's computer. That will populate the apturls file. Transfer that file to the system that has the internet connection. It doesn't matter if this system has that package installed or not. The second command fetches the necessary deb files and puts them in a folder. Copy that folder to the first computer and run the third command. I hope that clears your doubts. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can Download Adobe Flash Player 30 for Windows 7/8/10, MAC and Linux from this URL.

Download Adobe Flash Player 30 2018 Version from https://offlineinstallersofts.com/free-download-adobe-flash-player-30-offline-installer.html﻿